# POST/Form Data from java

Tags: java, forms, post, unity-game-engine

I'm looking to make some requests to some pages I've made that submit data to a DB.

Using the game engine Unity, this is the best way to write to a DB.  The WWWForm class makes it really snappy.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html

I'm not super familiar with Java, is there a similar kind of library or process built in?  I want to write to this MySQL DB via the web services I've already created (just submit some form data with my POST request a la the WWWForm library).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called `JDBC` Java Database Connectivity API. This is used to do all DB operations. But depending on your environment, there are flavors.

Check out [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)